# Remove duplicate category string by delimeter in Excel cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following categories data in a cell

Business Services -> ISO Consultants ##  Business Services -> Trademark Consultants ##  Electronics and Home Appliances -> Water Purifiers

I want to check for duplicate categories and remove if found within a cell. The delimiter is ##.

In the above example I want the following output:

Business Services -> ISO Consultants ## Trademark Consultants ##  Electronics and Home Appliances -> Water Purifiers

As you can see the string "Business Services ->" is removed because I had the same in the previous delimiter. So far I have tried many vb script like the following =returnUniques(Q2,"##")

```
Function returnUniques(S As String, Delim As String) As String
    Dim strOut   As String
    Dim Arr      As Variant
    Dim intCount As Integer
    Arr = VBA.Split(S, Delim)
    For intCount = LBound(Arr) To UBound(Arr)
        If Application.Match(Arr(intCount), Arr, 0) = intCount + 1 Then strOut = strOut & Arr(intCount) & Delim
    Next
    returnUniques = Left$(strOut, Len(strOut) - 1)
End Function
```

but its not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a variation of Jeeped's answer. It is guaranteed to return a string where the items are in their original order, with the first occurrence of the duplicate kept. It has been modified to keep the portion of the duplicate after `"->"`:

```
Option Explicit

Function returnUniques(S As String, Optional Delim As String = "##") As String
    Dim fields As Variant
    Dim prefix As String
    Dim Arr As Variant
    Dim Keep As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Dim Dict As Variant

    Set Dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    Arr = VBA.Split(S, Delim)
    ReDim Keep(0 To UBound(Arr))

    For i = 0 To UBound(Arr)
        fields = Split(Arr(i), "->")

        If UBound(fields) > 0 Then
            If Not Dict.Exists(Trim(fields(0))) Then
                Dict.Add Trim(fields(0)), ""
                Keep(i) = Arr(i)
            Else
                Keep(i) = fields(1)
            End If
        Else
            Keep(i) = Arr(i)
        End If
    Next i

    returnUniques = Join(Keep, Delim)
End Function
```

Comment: setting the dictionary as static significantly helps load time when using in a udf down a long column.

Comment: it does not work, it outputs Business Services -> ISO Consultants##Business Services -> Trademark Consultants##Electronics and Home Appliances -> Water Purifiers

Comment: That aspect of the  problem is easy to overlook in the problem description -- you in effect have *two* delimiters but only focused on one. In any event, I modified the code to handle this complication.

Comment: A potential issue with the code is the following: if things such as e.g.  "Business Services -> ISO Consultants" were *interspersed* with things such as "Electronics and Home Appliances -> Water Purifiers" then something like "Electronics" might be tacked onto something which goes "Electronics and Home Appliances" rather than something which goes with "Business Services". If this is an issue, then the code would have to be tweaked (by storing things like "Water Purifiers" in the *values* of the dictionary, reassembling them at the end).

Answer (score 1):

Try gaining uniqueness with a dictionary.

```
Option Explicit

Function udfUniqueList(str As String, _
                       Optional delim As String = "##", _
                       Optional cs As Boolean = False)
    Dim a As Long, arr As Variant
    Static dict As Object

    If dict Is Nothing Then
        Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    End If
    dict.RemoveAll
    dict.CompareMode = IIf(cs, vbBinaryCompare, vbTextCompare)

    arr = Split(str, delim)
    For a = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        dict.Item(arr(a)) = a
    Next a

    udfUniqueList = Join(dict.keys, delim)

End Function
```

Comment: not working, it outputs Business Services -> ISO Consultants##Business Services -> Trademark Consultants##Electronics and Home Appliances -> Water Purifiers